# Manipulating unevaluated expressions in nested function calls

Tags: function-construction, associations, hold

This is a follow-up to my earlier question: [Passing an unevaluated part of an association to a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88442/passing-an-unevaluated-part-of-an-association-to-a-function)

I'm trying to create a modular dashboard that controls sound volume of an audio system consisting of several speakers.

System settings are given by the following association:

```
speakers = <|
    "speaker1" -> <|"volume" -> 0.5|>, 
    "speaker2" -> <|"volume" -> 0.7|>
|>
```

I have a simple widget `AdjustOneSpeaker` that takes in a part of the `speakers` variable corresponding to one of the speakers, and dynamically adjusts its volume using a slider:

```
SetAttributes[AdjustOneSpeaker, HoldAll];

AdjustOneSpeaker[speaker_] := {
   Slider[Dynamic[speaker["volume"]]], 
   Dynamic[speaker["volume"]]
};
```

Passing `speakers["speaker1"]` to this widget works fine:

```
AdjustOneSpeaker[speakers["speaker1"]]
```

To use `AdjustOneSpeaker` function as a building block for a composite dashboard, I must be able to map it over the `speakers` association (i.e. over all speakers):

```
SetAttributes[AdjustAllSpeakers, HoldAll];

AdjustAllSpeakers[speakers_] := AdjustOneSpeaker /@ speakers // Values;
```

Unfortunately, this operation forces an evaluation of the individual parts of `speakers` **before** they are passed to `AdjustOneSpeaker`, making it impossible for the slider to set the volume fields of the global `speakers` association (since its argument is no longer a reference to the global field, but an association literal):

```
AdjustAllSpeakers[speakers]
```

> Association::setps: <|volume->0.5|> in the part assignment is not a
>   symbol. >>

Is there a way to pass an unevaluated part of an unevaluated `speakers` association to `AdjustOneSpeaker` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I urge you to consider a method like the one below as I think it will ultimately make your coding experience easier, for the specific example in hand you can prevent the unwanted evaluation by writing `speakers` inside `AdjustOneSpeaker` where it is held (by `HoldAll`).  Note also that you need to map over the [`Keys`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Keys.html) of the association, not its values.

```
AdjustOneSpeaker[speakers@#] & /@ Keys[speakers] // Grid
```

[image]

#### Conceptual handling of active expressions

In my opinion you should try to avoid passing around expressions like `speakers["speaker1"]` for the very reason of the evaluation that brought about your question.  This is similar to defining functions/procedures like `doSometing := Print[foo]` whereas I always write `doSomething[] := Print[foo]` instead as the latter lets me pass `doSometing` around without fear of evaluation.

In your application you might define a new head like so:

```
SetAttributes[ascSpec, HoldFirst];
ascSpec[asc__][part__] := ascSpec[asc, part]
```

Now you can map it onto the Keys of `speakers` without unwanted action:

```
ascSpec[speakers] /@ Keys[speakers]
```

> ```
> {ascSpec[speakers, "speaker1"], ascSpec[speakers, "speaker2"]}
> ```

You would then define your slider maker to handle this container:

```
SetAttributes[adjust1, HoldAll];

adjust1[ascSpec[asc_, parts___] | asc_] :=
  {Slider[Dynamic[asc[parts, "volume"]]],  Dynamic[asc[parts, "volume"]]};

adjust1 /@ {ascSpec[speakers, "speaker1"], ascSpec[speakers, "speaker2"]} // Grid
```

[image]

#### Playing with `Unevaluated`

As an example of the kind of gymnastics the method above is intended to avoid here is an example of trying to solve the problem by way of [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html).  Admittedly I am not giving this my best effort and there may be a cleaner form but I am also not making this intentionally baroque.  I'll show the process step by step so you can watch the transformation:

```
Keys[speakers]
Hold @@ %
Unevaluated[speakers] /@ %
AdjustOneSpeaker /@ %
List @@ % // Grid
```

> ```
> {"speaker1", "speaker2"}
>
> Hold["speaker1", "speaker2"]
>
> Hold[speakers["speaker1"], speakers["speaker2"]]
>
> Hold[AdjustOneSpeaker[speakers["speaker1"]], AdjustOneSpeaker[speakers["speaker2"]]]
> ```
>
> [image]