# Prepend multiple list with a same header

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

If I have a header and I want this header to be prepended to every list but apparently the Map (`\@`) function does not work with `PrependTo`. Here are my code.

```
data1={{1,1},{1,1}};
data2={{2,2},{2,2}};
data3={{3,3},{3,3}};
data4={{4,4},{4,4}};

header = {"A", "B"};
PrependTo[#, header] & /@ {data1,data2,data3,data4}
```

I got:

```
{PrependTo[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {"A", "B"}], 
 PrependTo[{{2, 2}, {2, 2}}, {"A", "B"}], 
 PrependTo[{{3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {"A", "B"}], 
 PrependTo[{{4, 4}, {4, 4}}, {"A", "B"}]}
```

which is not evaluated. I guess it to do with `PrependTo`. Any idea to fix this?

The reason I was using `PrependTo` was I want to do

```
Export["data.xlsx",{"data1" -> data1, "data2" -> data2, "data3" -> data3, "data4" -> data4}]
```

i.e., I did want the lists to be updated before exporting.

Many thanks.
Leo

Comment: Use `Prepend` instead of `PrependTo`. The latter tries to reset the value of a symbol given as its argument, and that fails when you try to reset the value of a list, which is not a symbol. See the Details section of the [docs for `PrependTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrependTo.html). As a side note, you should also get a number of errors during your evaluation, which have a pretty good hint at why your original code does not work. If you don't see them, you might want to check that you haven't silenced those messages somehow.

Comment: I did try `Prepend` but how to make it work with `/@` (in pure function form) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Map` does not work with `PrependTo` because `Map` does not hold its variables and `PrependTo` requires a variable so that it can prepend to the value of that variable.

That is, `Map` does not pass `data1` to `PrependTo`. Instead it resolves `data1` to its value, `{{1,1},{1,1}}`, and then passes this value to `PrependTo`.  However, `PrependTo` needs a variable (not the value of a variable).

You can get around this by using `Prepend` as @WReach has suggested.

```
{data1, data2, data3, data4} = Prepend[#, header] & /@ {data1, data2, data3, data4};
```

However, if your *data** values are sufficiently large that you do not want to do the copy-prepend-assign then there is a solution with `` GeneralUtilities`HoldMap ``.

```
GeneralUtilities`HoldMap[PrependTo[#, header] &, {data1, data2, data3, data4}];
```

Then

```
data1
```

> ```
> {{"A", "B"}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}
> ```

and similarly for the other variables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: It seems I don't have ``GeneralUtilities`HoldMap`` in v10.1.  I am betting it is based on `Unevaluated`.  Would you mind posting the code so I can see?  `PrintDefinitions @ HoldMap`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It was introduced in either 10.3 or 10.4.  The code with its helper functions is too large to post in a comment.  The first argument must be a `Function` form and with a bit of metaprogramming it inserts the `HoldFirst` attribute.  There is also `HoldScan` which produces essentially the same form as in my response.  @Edmund: nice find +1.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Prepend` instead of `PrependTo`.

```
Prepend[#, header] & /@ {data1, data2, data3, data4}

(* { {{A,B},{1,1},{1,1}},
     {{A,B},{2,2},{2,2}},
     {{A,B},{3,3},{3,3}},
     {{A,B},{4,4},{4,4}} } *)
```

The difference is that `PrependTo` not only creates a new list with a prepended element but it also assigns the result back to the variable in the first argument:

```
myList = {1, 2, 3};

PrependTo[myList, "abc"]
(* {"abc", 1, 2, 3} *)

myList
(* {"abc", 1, 2, 3} *)
```

Contrast this to `Prepend`, which does not update the variable:

```
myList = {1, 2, 3};

Prepend[myList, "abc"]
(* {"abc", 1, 2, 3} *)

myList
(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

The first argument to `PrependTo` *must* be an assignable variable:

```
PrependTo[{1, 2, 3}, "abc"]
(* PrependTo::rvalue:
     {1,2,3} is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed. *)
```

... but `Prepend` makes no such demand:

```
Prepend[{1, 2, 3}, "abc"]
(* {"abc", 1, 2, 3} *)
```

For this reason, `Prepend` is more suitable for use with higher-level functions such as `Map`.

**Responding to the Updated Question**

If we wish to update the original variables, we need to prevent the evaluation of the individual variables.  For example:

```
Scan[Function[Null, PrependTo[#, {"A", "B"}], HoldFirst], Hold[data1, data2, data3, data4]]

data1
(* {{"A","B"},{1,1},{1,1}} *)

data2
(* {{'A","B"},{2,2},{2,2}} *)

data3
(* {{"A","B'},{3,3},{3,3}} *)

data4
(* {{"A","B"},{4,4},{4,4}} *)
```

Note the use of `Hold` to prevent the variable list from being evaluated and the use of the `HoldFirst` attribute on the pure function for the same purpose.

**A Plague Of (and On) Held Expressions**

All of this holding seems very complicated for such a simple operation.  This is unfortunately a common occurrence when working with held expressions.  Since the first argument to `PrependTo` must be held, our mapped operator must hold that argument as well.  Which, in turn, means that the list over which we wish to iterate must be held as well.  And so on up the chain.

Held expressions are contagious, and once we want to start iterating over them they spread like the plague.  In this simple example, there were two prospects for error: if we had omitted the `Hold` or `HoldFirst`.  But in more complex programs the chance for so-called "evaluation leaks" to spring up grows quickly.

All of the built-in destructive operators (like `PrependTo`, `Set`, `SetDelayed` etc) require held arguments.  In other languages, programs involving destructive operators are harder to reason about on account of their side-effects (*I found the bug but... the original values are now overwritten and lost. whoops*).  But in *Mathematica*, destructive operators have the additional complication of potential evaluation leaks and hold-contagion.

This is why the *Mathematica* documentation stresses the transformative and functional programming styles -- precisely to avoid such complexity.

In the case at hand, the desired list can be created directly in a functional style:

```
Thread[{"data1","data2","data3","data4"} -> Prepend[header] /@ {data1,data2,data3,data4}]

(* { "data1" -> {{"A", "B"}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}
   , "data2" -> {{"A", "B"}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}}
   , "data3" -> {{"A", "B"}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}
   , "data4" -> {{"A", "B"}, {4, 4}, {4, 4}}
   } *)
```

There is no need to overwrite the original variables.  (*in earlier versions of Mathematica the operator mapped may need to be written as* `Prepend[#, header]&`)

Comment: In fact, I do need the lists to be updated for exporting. --- I have updated my questions. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I have updated my response for the new requirement.

Comment: Thanks !  slightly complicated.

Comment: That is very clever.  An attributed pure function with slots, a held *sequence* of assigned symbols, and all bundled up in `Scan`. (+1) Very clever, indeed.

Comment: @Leo1215 Indeed... held expressions breed complexity.  I added a discussion on this point.

Answer (score 5):

#### `Unevaluated`

You can `Map` [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) over the held Symbols to keep `PrependTo[#, header] &` from evaluating each of them too soon.

```
Unevaluated /@ Hold[data1, data2, data3, data4] // Scan[# ~PrependTo~ header &]

data3
```

> ```
> {{"A", "B"}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}
> ```

---

#### Automated solutions

A slight modification to a [method from WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/461/121) gives us a very clean solution:

```
SetAttributes[vars, HoldAll]
vars /: s : _[_vars, _] := CompoundExpression @@ Thread[Unevaluated @ s, vars, 1];
```

Now just write:

```
PrependTo[vars[data1, data2, data3, data4], header];
```

We could also apply [my `autoThread` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138661/121#138663), still under development:

```
PrependTo[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, header] // autoThread;
```

---

#### Alternative approach

If you wish to avoid all of this consider using [indexed objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) to store you data:

```
data[1] = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
data[2] = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}};
data[3] = {{3, 3}, {3, 3}};
data[4] = {{4, 4}, {4, 4}};

header = {"A", "B"};
```

This allows you to use:

```
PrependTo[data[#], header] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Or:

```
Array[PrependTo[data[#], header] &, 4];
```

Or:

```
Do[PrependTo[data[i], header], {i, 4}]
```

Recommended reading:

- [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)
- [Manipulating unevaluated expressions in nested function calls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88892/manipulating-unevaluated-expressions-in-nested-function-calls/88931#88931)

Comment: Very interesting techniques used here. (+1) Learned somethings new.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
b = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}};
c = {{3, 3}, {3, 3}};
d = {{4, 4}, {4, 4}};

header = {"A", "B"};
```

Using `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2)

```
{a, b, c, d} //= Map @ Prepend @ header;

{a, b, c, d}
```

{{{"A", "B"}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{"A", "B"}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}}, {{"A",
"B"}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{"A", "B"}, {4, 4}, {4, 4}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
b = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}};
c = {{3, 3}, {3, 3}};
d = {{4, 4}, {4, 4}};

header = {"A", "B"};
```

Using `MapThread` and `Insert`:

```
MapThread[Insert[#1, #2, 1] &, {#, Array[header &, Length@#]}] &@{a, b, c, d}
```

> {{{"A", "B"}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{"A", "B"}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}}, {{"A",
> "B"}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{"A", "B"}, {4, 4}, {4, 4}}}